# creating tables in existing database sqlite sugar orm

Tags: java, android, sqlite, orm, sugarorm

I have existing database that I have created using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, but now I want to move to Sugar Orm and trying to add new tables in existing databases. I am following all the points mentioned on configuration page of sugar orm page ([Sugar Orm Configuration](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html)).

Here is how my configuration looks like,

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name=".application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="database.db" />
    <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="5" />
    <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.example.in.smart" />
```

application.java (Application class)

```
public class application extends com.orm.SugarApp
 {
private static Context instance;
 public static Context get() {
    return application.instance;
}
```

Model class

```
public class Now extends SugarRecord<Now> {
public String type = null;
public String name = null;
public String address = null;
public Date created;

public Now(){}

public Now(String type, String name,String address,Date created){
    super();
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.created = created;
}
```

}

```
@Override public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    instance = getApplicationContext();
    //ACRA.init(this);
}
```

}

adding data process

```
   Now now = new Now(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get(i).name, entry.getValue().get(i).address, calendar.getTime());
  now.save(); // throws exception here
```

But I get this exception

```
E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: NOW
 E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting ADDRESS=abc TYPE=Now NAME=tyy CREATED=1430229379156
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: NOW (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO NOW(ADDRESS,TYPE,NAME,CREATED) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
        at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:126)
        at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:45)
```

any suggestion coz for me it looks like I am doing everything right. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the stack trace?

Comment: updated the stack trace

Comment: Did you go through the [Database Migrations instructions](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/migration.html) too? You'll have to bump up the version and provide an upgrade script that creates the new `Now` table - this will *not* automagically happen.

Comment: Yes, I updated version in AndroidManifest from 4 to 5 ..

Comment: @user3290805: Please add the file name, location and contents of your upgrade script to your question.

Comment: sorry I did not get which file name and location ?

Comment: @user3290805: of your **upgrade script**. Please have another read through the link I referred to one comment earlier if you're still confused. Based on your replies, it sounds like you simply forgot to do the database migration step in which your new table is to be created.

Answer (score 5):

the same happened to me, and the solution was only up the database version in the manifest:

From:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="VERSION"
            android:value="2" />
```

To:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="VERSION"
            android:value="3" />
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The `INSERT INTO` statement is not valid:

```
INSERT INTO NOW(ADDRESS,TYPE,NAME,CREATED) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

You try to insert 5 values instead of 4. (note the 5 question marks).

I guess `SugarRecord` conains an id which is mandatory.

Comment: then it should be problem in constructor instead of no table found, actually I check it was equal number of ? in insert Into, I already updated it in question

Comment: For some reason the table does not exist. It cannot be deduced from your code samples why.

Comment: yes, that what is the issue, but this is exactly I have in my code..any hints?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Maybe you want to debug into the line where the constructor gets called. Maybe the values passed are wrong.

Comment: Does the table created by SugarOrm model class allows null ?

Comment: I have no idea. I haven't used `SugarOrm` (or heard of it) before. I suggest you should check its source code (if available).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Now now = new Now(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get(i).name, entry.getValue().get(i).address, calendar.getTime());
> ```

Got the same problem. Check if one of your entries is "null".

Sugar ORM does not support null values. Please increment the version of database too.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling instant run, sugar orm doesn't work with instant run.